# Change _constraints to _sql_constraints - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo

I've noticed that there are almost none `_constraints` declarations on Odoo v10 community modules, but there are a lot of `_sql_constraints`

Is the `_constraints` been deprecated, or just a coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_constraints` is list of `(constraint_function, message, fields)` defining Python constraints. The fields list is indicative

Deprecated since version 8.0: use [`constrains()`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.api.constrains)

`_sql_constraints` list of `(name, sql_definition, message)` triples defining SQL constraints to execute when generating the backing table